# Singularity of solutions of a differential equation as functions of its eigenvalue

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, sturm-liouville, singularity-theory

This may be a naive question and I apologize if it's not stated concisely and rigorously.  I try to pose it first, and then explain my thoughts and comments on it; so please bear with me.

Let $\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of the Sturm-Liouville problem $Ly_n=\lambda_n y_n$ with homogeneous boundary conditions $y_n(x)=0$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$. Now consider $Ly_\lambda=\lambda y_\lambda$ with inhomogeneous boundary conditions $y_\lambda(0)=0$ and $y_\lambda(1)=1$. The questions is: Under what conditions is the following statement true?

$y_\lambda$, as a function of $\lambda$, has poles at $\lambda_n$ [for almost all $x\in(0,1)$].

This statement is true for $L=-d^2/dx^2$ where $\lambda_n=n^2\pi^2$ and $y_\lambda = \sin\sqrt\lambda x / \sin\sqrt\lambda$.  I can argue for it in a suggestive way that may be generalizable to other cases.  The general solution of $Ly=\lambda y$ for $\lambda\neq\lambda_n$ is $y(0) y_{10}(x) + y(1) y_{01}(x)$, where $y_{01} = \sin\sqrt\lambda x/ \sin\sqrt\lambda$ satisfies the inhomogeneous boundary condition $y_{01}(0)=0$ and $y_{01}(1)=1$.  Similarly $y_{10} = \cos\sqrt\lambda x - \cos\sqrt\lambda y_{01}$ satisfies $y_{10}(0)=1$ and $y_{10}(1)=0$.  Now I expect to recover $y_n(x)$ from either $y(0) y_{10}(x)$ or $y(1) y_{01}(x)$ as $\lambda\to\lambda_n$, if I properly carry out a limiting procedure to approach the homogeneous boundary conditions by sending $y(0)$ or $y(1)$ to zero.  For example, in the current case, I can take $y(1) \equiv c(\lambda) = \sin\sqrt\lambda$.  More generally, and adding an explicit label to denote the $\lambda$-dependence, I expect $$\lim_{\lambda\to\lambda_n} c(\lambda) y^{(\lambda)}_{01}(x) = y_n(x).$$  [This $y^{(\lambda)}_{01}$ is the same as the $y_\lambda$ I defined above.]  Since $y_n$ is almost always nonzero and I have $\lim_{\lambda\to\lambda_n} c(\lambda) = 0$, I get $\lim_{\lambda\to\lambda_n} y^{(\lambda)}_{01} = \infty$, as claimed.  Of course, this was by no means a rigorous argument.

I have a couple of additional comments.  First, being a physicist, I grant all nice smoothness assumptions on various functions.  Second, I am also interested in situations where one of the boundary conditions is of Neumann type (on the derivative of $y$).  Last, but not least, I'd like to know if and when a similar statement holds for a PDE on a domain $\Omega$.  That is, for a general (maybe elliptic?) linear operator $L$, let $y_n$ be the solutions of $Ly_n=\lambda_n y_n$ with a homogeneous boundary condition $y(\partial\Omega)=0$ (or a Neumann boundary condition), where $\partial\Omega$ has two disconnected components $\partial\Omega_0$ and $\partial\Omega_1$.  Then let $y_\lambda$ be the solution of $Ly_\lambda=\lambda y_\lambda$ with $y_\lambda(\partial\Omega_0)=0$ and $y_\lambda(\partial\Omega_1)=1$.  How are the singularities of $y_\lambda$ related to the spectrum of $L$?

Comment: I assume when you identify "$y(\lambda,x)$" you exclude the eigenvalues from the domain? If not, what is $y(\lambda_n,x)$? (Your question is sensible even with the domain punctured in this way.)

Comment: @Ian: That's right. I have excluded $\lambda_n$ from the domain of $\lambda$ by saying $\lambda\neq\lambda_n$.

Comment: Oh, I see, it was in the discussion further down.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is any non-trivial solution of $Lu=\lambda u$ for which $u(0,\lambda)=0$, then
$$
        v(x,\lambda)= \frac{u(x,\lambda)}{u(1,\lambda)}
$$
is a solution of $Lv=\lambda v$ for which $v(0,\lambda)=0$, $v(1,\lambda)=1$, unless $u(1,\lambda)=0$, in which case $v(1,\lambda)$ has a pole of order $1$ at $\lambda=1$.

Comment: The $y(x,\lambda)$ you defined satisfies $y_x(1,\lambda)=1$. But the function $y(x,\lambda)$ of interest to me satisfies $y(1,\lambda)=1$. (note the existence vs nonexistence of the derivative on $y$). Furthermore, I don't talk about a pole at $\lambda=0$; rather about poles at $\lambda_n$ (the spectrum of $L$).